# Cleaner case statements inside of queries?

Tags: sql, variables, alias

I'm doing an insert, and one of the values I'm inserting is calculated as follows:

```
SUM(Value1)/(
    CASE SUM(
        CASE Value2 > 0 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
        END
    ) = 0 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE SUM(
        CASE Value2 > 0 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END
    )
)
```

The inner `CASE`-part is duplicated twice, it would be nice to set an alias or variable to this value and use that alias or variable instead.

Comment: What flavour of SQL?  Can you use CommonTableExpressons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTE answer...

```
WITH
  step1 AS
(
  SELECT
    SUM(value1)                            AS interimValue1
    SUM(CASE value2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS interimValue2,
    <other fields>
  FROM
    <a query>
)
SELECT
  interimValue / CASE interimValue2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE interimValue2 END
FROM
  step1
```

SubQuery version...

```
SELECT
  interimValue / CASE interimValue2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE interimValue2 END
FROM
(
  SELECT
    SUM(value1)                            AS interimValue1
    SUM(CASE value2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS interimValue2,
    <other fields>
  FROM
    <a query>
)
  AS step1
```

Or, more specific to the SQL you posted, but not an answer to the generic case...

```
SUM(value1) / COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN value2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END), 1)
```

*(Returning NULL where you return 0 allows COALESCE to replace NULLs with 1s.)*

Comment: Didn't pay enough attention to your answer at first. Your last suggestion about returning NULL instead 0 is actually a brilliant idea! Spares you a `NULLIF` call which I had to include in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SUM(Value1) / COALESCE(NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN Value2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0), 1)
```

`NULLIF` will yield `NULL` if the result of `SUM` equals to `0`, otherwise it will return the result of `SUM`. `COALESCE` will leave the result of `NULLIF` unchanged if it is not `NULL`, otherwise `1` will be returned.